# JPA: LEFT JOIN in NamedQuery

Tags: jpa, join, named

I'm trying to do a left outer join on multiple tables in a namedquery. I need the left outer join because not all "carts" have a "hat" AND "shirt". I've simplified the example. My model looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Cart {


  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Shirt.class, optional = true)
  @JoinColumn(nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Shirt shirt;

  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Hat.class, optional = true)
  @JoinColumn(nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Hat hat;

  ...
}
```

My Query looks like this:

```
<query>
  SELECT
    _cart
  FROM
    Cart _cart
  LEFT JOIN
    _cart.hat _hat
  LEFT JOIN             
    _cart.shirt _shirt
  WHERE
    _hat.size = 's' OR _shirt.color = 'red'
</query>
```

The problem I'm experiencing is the query that gets generated does the LEFT JOINs AND the INNER JOINs (both tables get joined twice). I tried the "optional" attribute on the @ManyToOne before manually putting in those left joins but it didn't change the join type.

I'm using the latest version of TomEE with OpenJPA.

Thank you for any help.